# PHP 5.5.3 on Win32 - cURL takes 400ms+ to resolve all domain names, even localhost

Tags: php, curl

I'm experiencing problems with a PHP web-service client since I upgraded a server from PHP 5.3.x to PHP 5.5.3.

I have this function to time how long cURL takes to execute a request:

```
function makeRequest($method, $uri) {
    global $requests;

    addTime("makeRequest");

    $curl = curl_init($uri);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER    , true ); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS     , 10   );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST , $method);

    //////////////////////////////

    addTime("curl_exec");
    $responseContent = curl_exec($curl);
    remTime("curl_exec");

    addTime("curl_getInfo");
    $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
    remTime("curl_getInfo");

    array_push( $requests, var_export( $responseInfo, true ) );

    remTime("makeRequest");
}
```

`addTime` and `remTime` are functions that log `microtime(true)` to accurately measure method execution. I'm also logging the different times reported by `curl_getinfo`). See below.

I tried it with a bunch of different URIs. These are my results:

#### `https://api1.mywebservice.com/methodCall`

- total_time - *0.406*
- namelookup_time - *0.0406*
- connect_time - *0.406*
- pretransfer_time - *0.406*
- starttransfer_time - *0.406*
- redirect_time - *0*

`makeRequest` time: *0.402*

#### `https://api2.mywebservice.com/methodCall`

api2.mywebservice.com is hardcoded into the machine's `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to `127.0.0.1` so it should never hit a DNS server for this

- total_time - *0.406*
- namelookup_time - *0.0406*
- connect_time - *0.0406*
- pretransfer_time - *0.0406*
- starttransfer_time - *0.0406*
- redirect_time - *0*

`makeRequest` time: *0.402*

#### `https://localhost/methodCall`

- total_time - *0.406*
- namelookup_time - *0.406*
- connect_time - *0.406*
- pretransfer_time - *0.406*
- starttransfer_time - *0.406*
- redirect_time - *0*

`makeRequest` time: *0.403*

#### `https://127.0.01/methodCall`

- total_time - *0*
- namelookup_time - *0*
- connect_time - *0*
- pretransfer_time - *0*
- starttransfer_time - *0*
- redirect_time - *0*

`makeRequest` time: *0.006*

The DNS server of the server is only about 5ms away, but the name should be cached anyway. The fact it gets the same times for `api2.mywebservice.com` shows that it is not an issue of the DNS server timing out, but something rotten inside cURL.

I also tried `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` but it had no effect:

```
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, array("api1.mywebservice.com:443:127.0.01") );
```

Why is cURL in the latest (and greatest, surely?) edition of PHP taking so long to retrieve a result?

Comment: Have you checked the DNS settings on the machine?

Comment: i highly doubt the problem is curl related, check your DNS settings with nslookup (or any other command line utilities), a 400ms should be easily detected.

Comment: `nslookup` returns instantly. This is a Windows Azure machine, Azure VMs use DHCP to get assigned a DNS server.

Comment: If you have more than 1 DNS server in your config, try to swap their order.

Comment: There is only 1 DNS server configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your libcurl is built to use it's own name resolver, instead of system name resolver. In this case it does not use hosts file at all.

There are 3 possible solutions of this:

1. update your php_curl.dll (current windows php binaries 5.5.4);
2. install local DNS server and configure it to use hosts file and configure your networking to use 127.0.0.1 as a DNS server;
3. Set CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE to true (turned on by default) and CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT to a larger value (2 mins by default);

**In addition:** php 5.5.4 windows binaries from php.net uses system resolver for curl. It uses internal cache (when enebled with `CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE`) and system DNS cache. I have checked it with some tests. A also checked the speed of name resolution by curl - it's identical to localhost (for any records written in hosts file). So, i'm absolutely shure it's not a PHP problem:

1. there is a mistake in `https://127.0.01/methodCall` must be `https://127.0.0.1/methodCall`. curl always return total_time = 0 in such cases.
2. first of all try to request static content like an empty file and use http instead of https.
3. disable all firewalls and uninstall all antivirus software (stopping antivirus software is not enought in some cases).
4. check web-server's virtual hosting configuration, and look at what you're requesting.
5. check all fields of `curl_getinfo($curl)`, especially `"primary_ip"`.

Comment: I updated my PHP 5.5.4 but this didn't fix the problem. I don't think cURL even has its own DNS cache at all because requesting the same hostname twice in a row takes just as long.

Comment: I've slightly improved my answer.